# How to clean up dataframe row in Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have a row in dataframe as

```
names
------
*OP Under A Blood Red Moon
125-201 1006
Apple
Orange
/
1-2-3
```

I wanna clean it up and just have

```
names
------
Apple
Orange
```

I wanna remove
`*OP Under A Blood Red Moon` as it has more than three words.

remove `125-201 1006` and `1-2-3` as they only have numbers and symbol.

remove `/` as it is less than one character.

I'm kinda familiar with how to do some of this in python for a string but how do I do this for an entire row in pandas dataframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than removing rows we filter them and retain any rows that:

- have no more than 3 words (i.e. no more than 2 separating spaces)  **AND**
- contain minimum one alpha character  **AND**
- are longer than 1 character

with the following boolean indexing:

```
def num_alpha(s):
    return len([c for c in s if c.isalpha()])

df[(df.names.str.count(' ') < 3) & (df.names.apply(num_alpha) > 0) & (df.names.str.len() > 1)]
```

This conditions, especially the first one, can certainly still be refined but I think you get the idea.

Please note that the **parentheses are necessary** when doing element-wise logical operations in pandas, see [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing).